# How to use White Correction for Heteroskedasticity in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I know that in eviews, after you run a regression you can select the option to use the White Correction for heteroskedasticity. However, I cannot find any way to use the White correction in R. Eviews is unnecessarily difficult when it comes to importing data (pretty much the worst GUI ever) and so I have decided to not use eviews ever again.

Is there any way to use the White correction for heteroskedasticity in R? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try the `sandwich` package.

Comment: To those who put my question on hold, I'm stumped. The answer to my question would be a package recommendation. There's either a package that has the White correction in it or there isn't. Sorry, but that's the way it is.

Comment: "Asks to recommend a package or tool" is one of the main reason questions are closed.  If you want to discuss further, please post on meta.stackoverflow.com (but do a search for similar questions there first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(car)
library(lmtest)
coeftest(mymodel, vcov= hccm(mymodel))
```